# Symfony 1.4 sf auth routing

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

Is there any idea how to write sfAuth routing for symfony 1.4? which is similar like

```
homepage:
 url:   /
 param: { module: default, action: index }

default_index:
  url:   /:module
  param: { action: index }

default:
  url:   /:module/:action/*
```

Comment: You just have to read [the doc](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/plugins/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/trunk/README#L191) ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write sfAuth for symfony is simple, just follow the similar way you define default routing

```
sf_guard_signin:
 url:   /login
 param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signin }

sf_guard_signout:
 url:   /logout
 param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: signout }

sf_guard_password:
 url:   /request_password
 param: { module: sfGuardAuth, action: password }
```

Hope this might give you some insight.

Comment: also dont forget to enable this at setting.yml
  .actions:  
    login_module:           sfGuardAuth
    login_action:           signin
    secure_module:          sfGuardAuth
    secure_action:          secure
    error_404_module:       default
    error_404_action:       error404